# $\inf_{k\geq n} f_k$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of non-negative measurable functions, $f_n : (\Omega, \cal{F}) \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$.  That is, they're measurable w.r.t $\cal{F}$ and $\cal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}}) = \Sigma$.  Define $g_n := \inf_{k\geq n} f_k$.  Then $g_n$ is a measurable for all $n$.

My attempt:  let $A$ be in $\Sigma$.  Then we can decompose $A$ into a union of singletons which are also in $\Sigma$.  Then $g_n^{-1}(\{a\}) = [\cap_{k\geq n} \{f_k \geq a\}] \cap [\cap_{1/m > 0, m\in\mathbb{N}^+}\cup_{k\geq n}\{f_k \lt a + 1/m\}]$.  Which is a weird combination of measurable sets in $\mathcal{F}$ involving countable intersections and unions so it should also be in there.  However to form $g_n^{-1}(A)$, I can do an arbitrary union of $g_n$ on the singletons $\{a\}$ but I need a countable one to show membership in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$.  So this approach is lacking.

Comment: As you say, singletons are not the right idea. Do you have any theorems about measurable functions that let you avoid trying to check an arbitrary element of $\Sigma$?

Comment: I think if $g_n^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F}$ for all closed sets $B$, then $g_n$ is measurable.  So I've heard, haven't proved it.

Comment: A function's measurable whenever the inverse images of a generating set for the range $\sigma$-algebra are measurable. The easiest set of generators is often the half-spaces $(a,\infty)$, or in your case $(b,\infty]$. If I were doing this I'd prove this fact first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from the previous chapter.  Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space.  Let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of measurable maps $f_n : (\Omega, \mathcal{F})\rightarrow (\bar{\mathbb{R}}, \mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}}))$.  Let g and h be the maps defined by $g(w) = \inf_{n\geq k} f_n(w)$ and $h(w) = \sup_{n\geq k} f_n(w)$, for all $w\in \Omega$.

1. Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$.  Show that $\{c \leq g\} = \cap_{n =k}^{+\infty}\{c\leq f_n\}$.
2. Similar for $h$.